# Format or Pattern for Decimal Numbers to display on axis on google charts

Tags: google-visualization

Good Morning,

When ever we create data table with certain data for **Column Chart i.e.**

```
**['Year', '% of ToTal Revenues ', '% of Total orders'],
['Feb12-July12',  0.25,      0.36],
['Aug12-Jan12',  0.58,      0.69],
['Feb13-July14',  0.47,       0.14],
['Aug13-Jan14',  0.62,      0.84]**
```

in the out put especially on VAxis   the graph was displaying **0.1 to 0.98..**
but when i a want to append **% symbol** to the given input values like **0.01%,0.02%,to 0.98% it** was converting decimal into natural numbers that for ex **0.65 into 65** so what type of pattern i have to pass     **forex** VAxis:{format:'#.##%'}}; 
Please Help Me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestood right, you want to keep it as decimals instead of 0.5 = 50%. This should do the trick:

```
 vAxis:{format: '#.#\'%\'' }
```

Comment: thank you very much Mr.juvian,i got my requirement. thank you